# zero-initialization и memset в конструкторе

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Аналогичны ли два этих конструктора?

```
struct Test
{
    int i;
    int j;
};

struct Fcn
{
    Test test;
    Fcn()
    {
        memset(&test, 0, sizeof(test));
    }
};
```

и

```
struct Fcn
{   
    Test test;
    Fcn(): test{}
    {
    }
};
```

Ведь по-сути компилятор вставляет тот же самый `memset` во втором случае. Или нет?

Comment: В случае нулевой инициализации по стандарту нет гарантии, что будет заполнен нулями возможный padding _между полями_. Больше разницы вроде бы нет.

Comment: Вопрос именно о данном случае: два поля типа `int`? Или вопрос о более общем случае?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В данном конкретном случае - да, ибо `memset(..., 0, ...)` для целочисленных типов гарантирует корректную нулевую инициализацию.

В общем случае - нет (даже если не рассматривать типы с нетривиальной конструкцией), ибо, например, для указательных, плавающих и некоторых других типов в общем случае не гарантируется корректной нулевой инициализации через `memset(..., 0, ...)`.

Пример, демонстрирующий разницу для многих популярных реализаций может выглядеть так

```
struct Test
{
  int Test::*i;
  int Test::*j;
};
```

т.к. нулевое значение указателя-на-член-данное обычно представляется битовым набором `0xFF...F`, а не нулевым набором битов.

Также следует принять во внимание замечание @VladD об инициализации паддинга.